# How can I generate a list of PDF Forms based on user input?

Tags: forms

I am looking to make a user-friendly "form" for the HR department but am not sure how to do it.

My goal is to display a list of PDF forms based on the type of employee is being hired.

The HR user would be asked to select option that pertain to the type of worker that is being hired (hourly/salary, type of employee, etc.)

Based on what is answered, certain forms will be given to the user to download.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the best way, but an easy way to do this would be to use core's taxonomy module. From the module's [docs](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy): "Taxonomy, a powerful core module, gives your sites use of the organizational keywords known in other systems as categories, tags, or metadata. It allows you to connect, relate and classify your website’s content."

In a nutshell, I'd suggest to create a taxonomy vocabulary for your type of workers, and add a term for each (hourly, salary, etc.) and attach a file field to the vocabulary, where you can upload and attach the PDFs for each term. Then on the front end, you can create a view that lists all of the file fields attached to that term.